# link_to array of objects but with new path

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, routes

I have a link that is generated from an array of objects...

```
<%= link_to 'Add a Post', [@object, Post.new], :action => 'new', :remote => true, :class => 'button gray medium' %>
```

however this only generates '/businesses/12/posts/' while I would like to have a '/new' at the end of it, therefore '/businesses/12/posts/new'. Is this possible with link_to array of objects? The :action => 'new' appears to do nothing in the case above.

The @object could be various types of objects so I can't use the new_business_post_path(). And each of these objects will have a resourceful route to posts

Comment: Figured it out, but still can't find this in any documentation and it was just a fluke that I found it.

[:new, @object, :post] translates to: new_businesses_post() helper

Comment: have you found any documentation? i'm looking to add the :format option

Comment: If I understand what you are asking, it would be like: link_to 'different format', [:new, @object, :post], :format => :pdf

Comment: The best documentation I've located is a 2012 post from Ryan Bigg at http://ryanbigg.com/2012/03/polymorphic-routes/ which really thoroughly details what's going on with the array form of routes

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The answer is to use:

```
[:new, @object, :post]
```

Which translates to:

```
new_businesses_post()
```