# Why does url_for [:new, Project] translate to new_projects_url (plural), not into new_project_url (singular)?

Tags: ruby-on-rails

```
$ url_for [Project]
=> projects_url
$ url_for [:new, Project]
=> new_projects_url
$ url_for [:new, Project, :test]
=> new_project_test_url
$ url_for [:new, Project, nil]
=> new_projects_url
```

I find `url_for [:new, Project, :test]` especially interesting: here `project` is singular!

Anyone has an idea how to generate a `new_project_url` (or path) from an array like `[:new, Project]`?

Comment: I found `url_for [:new, Project.name.underscore]` to be working (thanks to [this other post](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7258531/link-to-array-of-objects-but-with-new-path)), but isn't there a more elegant way?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
url_for([:new, :project])
```

Will do the trick.

Comment: In your case, `@project` is an instance of a `Project`. Trying to call a `new` action on an existing `@project` doesn't make sense.

Comment: Oops, typo. The instance variable can be used for the edit action.

Comment: Thank you. This helps, but isn't there an easier way to find get `:project` out of `Project` than `Project.name.underscore`?

Answer (score 1):

When using `[:new, Project]`, `:new` is a namespace.